# When I create a scene as a Linked Copy, is it possible to have certain objects not linked?

Tags: linked-data, scene

When I create a new Scene which is a Linked Copy. Is it possible to remove specific objects from being linked between scenes?

Comment: You could do Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data & Materials, but it will also unlink the object from its linked copy in the same scene. I don't know if there's another method. It doesn't seem to work for lights in 2.8 though, but it works fine in 2.79, so I guess it needs to be reported.